# jQuery: textfield name selector

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form:

```
<form id="userForm" action="xpto">
     <input type="text" name="form[data_nascimento_beneficiario_1]" value />
     <input type="submit" value="Continuar" />
</form>
```

Now on a script file i try to get the lenght of the field for validation:

```
$("#userForm").submit(function (e) {
     alert($("input[name="form[data_nascimento_beneficiario_1]"]).length());
});
```

But i always get "TypeError: Cannot call method 'length' of null",

I guess the problem is on the name to have "form[]", but that is nothing i can change :(

Can anyone help me please?

Regards to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues there:

1. Your code as quoted actually has a syntax error and so wouldn't give you the error you've said, you've ended your JavaScript string just after the word `name`.
2. When the attribute value you're testing contains anything but the letters A-Z, it's best to put it in quotes.
3. `length` is "th" at the end, not "ht"
4. ...and in jQuery [it's a *property*](http://api.jquery.com/length/), not a method, so you don't want `()` after it
5. The name you're using in your selector (`data_nascimento_baneficiario_1`) doesn't match the name in the form (`data_nascimento_beneficiario_1`), note the "a" at the beginning of "baneficiario" in the selector.

All together: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iQuluNi/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iQuluNi/1/edit)

```
alert($('input[name="form[data_nascimento_beneficiario_1]"]').length);
```

(There, I've used `'` to put quotes around the selector string and `"` to put quotes around the attribute value. The other way around also works.)

Comment: I have also tryed that out, but no i give's me the same error.

Comment: @NunoSimões: Your code as quoted can't give you the error you've said, so it sounds like perhaps you're not editing the right file or some such. Also note #4 in the above (hit refresh if you don't see a numbered list).

Comment: @NunoSimões: I was doing a live example and found a fifth issue.

Comment: ty for your help. The code i have is really extensive, so i have made a short version of it, sorry about that.

The 'th' have been changed, sorry for the typo.

The '()' part has also been tryed out without it, but i get always the same error "TypeError: Cannot call method 'length' of null", it like the element does not exist, but it does!

Comment: @NunoSimões: You shouldn't get that error message from jQuery. Are you sure you're using jQuery and not Prototype or MooTools (which also use `$`)? Because jQuery will always give you back a non-`null` result. It may be an empty set, but it won't be `null`. Prototype, MooTools, and the DOM itself will give you `null` if they can't find something, but not jQuery, which is set-based.

Comment: I'm trying to run this on Chrome console, probably that is the problem...

I have mounted this test http://jsfiddle.net/ku2wT/ and your right T.J. Sorry for all the trouble, probably the problem is on the chrome console not working has I expected, put probably on runtime on my code it works. Thank for all(all you guy's) your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: `.lenght()` - it should be `length`. Also, be careful about your quote wrapping.

Change your line to this:

```
alert($("input[name='form[data_nascimento_baneficiario_1]']).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, and length is not a function() so there is no need of invoking it with ()

Change this

`lenght()`

to

`length`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/xRr8f/)

Answer (score 0):

Note sure why that is not working but a workaround would be

```
$("input").filter(function(){ 
     return this.name = 'form[data_nascimento_beneficiario_1]'}
).val().length
```